# "while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))" might be empty?

Tags: php, crud

Im really confused now please help
... This is the edit/update part which you will edit chosen user. The problem is i think $row or array is empty. The problem is that part. Im accepting any advice to my code to make it better.

---

### Output

[This is the output when i click edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCj8i.png)

---

### update.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="uprec.php">
<?php  

if(isset($_POST["borrower_id"])){
    
    $output = '';
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "librarydb");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_books WHERE id = '".$_POST["borrower_id"]."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    echo "Connected ";
 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "fetch success";

    }
    echo "fetch failed";
  
}

else{
    echo "Not Connected";
}

?>
    <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="UPDATE" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### database.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Database</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script/livesearch.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Books</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Transactions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accounts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <?php
 if(!empty($_SESSION)) {
?>
    <div class="container p-3">
      <h1 class="">Library Database</h1>
      <hr><br>
      <form>
        <div class="input-group ">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Search</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </form>
      <br />
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addbook_modal">Add Book</button>
      <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <?php
 }else echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
    <strong>Login Required!</strong> You needed to be login first before you can access the database.
    <a href="login.php"> Go back to login</a>
    </div>';
?>
</body>

</html>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#addbook_form').on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($('#booktitle').val() == "") {
        alert("Book Title is required");
      } else if ($('#category').val() == '') {
        alert("Category is required");
      } else if ($('#author').val() == '') {
        alert("Author is required");
      } else if ($('#publishername').val() == '') {
        alert("Publisher Name is required");
      } else if ($('#datepublished').val() == '') {
        alert("Date Published is required");
      } else if ($('#copies').val() == '') {
        alert("Copies is required");
      } else {
        $.ajax({
          url: "insert.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: $('#addbook_form').serialize(),
          beforeSend: function() {
            $('#addbtn').val("Inserting");
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#addbook_form')[0].reset();
            $('#addbook_modal').modal('hide');
            $('#result').html(data);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '#editbtn', function() {
    var borrower_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
      url: "update.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        borrower_id: borrower_id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#borrower_detail').html(data);
        $('#editbook_modal').modal('show');
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="addbook_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Book</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" id="addbook_form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Book Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="booktitle" id="booktitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Title of the Book">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Category:</label>
            <select name="category" id="category" class="custom-select">
              <option>Art</option>
              <option>English</option>
              <option>Math</option>
              <option>Science</option>
              <option>Filipino</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Author:</label>
            <input type="text" name="author" id="author" class="form-control" placeholder="Author of the Book">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Publisher Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="publishername" id="publishername" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of the Publisher">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date Published</label>
            <input type="date" name="datepublished" id="datepublished" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Publication">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Copies</label>
            <input type="number" name="copies" id="copies" class="form-control" placeholder="Number of Copies">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button id="addbtn" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="editbook_modal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Book Details</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="borrower_detail">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### fetch.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
include ('connection.php');
 if(!empty($_SESSION)) {
  $output = '';
  if(isset($_POST["query"]))
  {
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "
      SELECT * FROM tbl_books
      WHERE booktitle LIKE '%".$search."%'
      OR category LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR author LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR copies LIKE '%".$search."%' 
      OR publishername LIKE '%".$search."%'
      OR datepublished LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ";
  }
  else
  {
    $query = "
      SELECT * FROM tbl_books ORDER BY id DESC
    ";
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {

    $output .= '
      <div class="table-responsive" id="employee_table">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
         <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Book Title</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Publisher Name</th>
            <th>Date Published</th>
            <th>Copies</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
    '; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

      $output .= '
        <tr>

         <td>'.$row["booktitle"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["category"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["author"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["publishername"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["datepublished"].'</td>
         <td>'.$row["copies"].'</td>
         <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="editbtn">Edit</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
         </td>
        </tr>
      ';
    }
    echo $output;
   }
  else
  {
    echo 'Data Not Found';
  }
 
 }else echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show">
        <strong>Login Required!</strong> You needed to be login first before you can access the database.
        <a href="login.php"> Go back to login</a>
        </div>';
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to execute the query on database directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently
    $_POST["borrower_id"]
is always "editbtn" all the time. So query always returns zero entries.

Your problem is this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="editbtn">Edit</button>
```

and this should probably something like this

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="editbtn" bookid='.$row['id'].'>Edit</button>
```

$row['id'] depends on whatever your id field is named.

Also you have to change

```
var borrower_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

to

```
var borrower_id = $(this).attr("bookid");
```

This should work.

Comment: As always, use mysql prepared statements. Dont write credentials for your database in code. Save them into some external file like .env .Use object oriented form for mysqli. Just look it up. Stick to some coding convention, there are a lot and the code is much better to understand.Try to extract some little functionalities into functions.